# react-native-firebase - Issue with migrating swift to react-native - iOS Pushes stop working

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, migration

I am migrating a swift app on FB 5.18 to RN firebase and pushes no longer work on migration. If I delete and redownload the RN version everything works. 
I've tried checking the token like so and I get both, but it still doesn't work. Permissions are enabled, requestPermission is just a precaution. I also poll this up to 50 times over a couple minutes until one is successful. Everything on Android works fine. I'm testing using the FCM test message tool with the FCM token.

```
Firebase.messaging().requestPermission()
await (Firebase.messaging() as any).ios.registerForRemoteNotifications()
const APNSToken = await (Firebase.messaging() as any).ios.getAPNSToken()
const token = Firebase.messaging().getToken()
if (APNSToken && token) sendToServer(token)
```

---

### Project Files

#### iOS

`ios/Podfile`:

- [x] I'm using Pods and my Podfile looks like:

```rb
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.18.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 5.18.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '~> 5.18.0'
```

`AppDelegate.m`:

```c
#import <Firebase.h>
#import "RNFirebaseNotifications.h"
#import "RNFirebaseMessaging.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  [RNFirebaseNotifications configure];
  ...
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(nonnull NSDictionary *)userInfo
                                                       fetchCompletionHandler:(nonnull void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{
  [[RNFirebaseNotifications instance] didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
  [[RNFirebaseMessaging instance] didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
```

---

### Environment

- **Platform that you're experiencing the issue on**:

  - [X] iOS
  - [ ] Android
  - [ ] **iOS** but have not tested behavior on Android
  - [ ] **Android** but have not tested behavior on iOS
  - [ ] Both
- **If known, the version of the platform are you experiencing the issue on:**

  - `All versions of iOS
- **`React Native` version:

  - `0.57.1`
- **`React Native Firebase` library version:**

  - `5.2.4`
- **`Firebase` module(s) you're using that has the issue:**

  - [ ] Authentication
  - [ ] Analytics
  - [ ] Cloud **Firestore**
  - [X] Cloud **Messaging** (FCM)
  - [ ] Crashlytics
  - [ ] Dynamic **Links**
  - [ ] **Functions** Callable
  - [ ] In App Messaging
  - [ ] Indexing
  - [ ] Invites
  - [ ] Instance ID
  - [ ] ML Kit
  - [X] Notifications
  - [ ] Performance Monitoring
  - [ ] Realtime **Database**
  - [ ] Remote **Config**
  - [ ] Storage
- **Are you using `TypeScript`?**

  - [ ] No
  - [X] Yes, version: `2.8.4`
- **Are you using Expo, e.g. `ExpoKit`?**

  - [x] No
  - [ ] Yes, I've *not* ejected
  - [ ] Yes, but I **have** ejected to `ExpoKit`
  - [ ] Yes, but I **have** ejected to vanilla React Native
  - Expo version: `N/A`

Answer (score 0):

Seems with react-native-firebase `Firebase.messaging().getToken()` will not return the latest token. My app was saving and using an old token and not updating a new one - very small race condition.

Simply use `Firebase.messaging.onTokenRefresh()` as a source of truth to avoid issues with migrating apps. Also to be sure you get a token that works. You may want to delete your token on a migration such as this with v4 -> `await Firebase.iid().deleteToken()`, or v5 `(Firebase.messaging().deleteToken()`. Then rely onTokenRefresh to send you a new one to send to your server.